# Django not applying default=0

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    MS_DRAFT, MS_NEW, MS_WAIT, MS_SENT, MS_DELETED, MS_GEOMSG, MS_ERROR  = range(7)
    MS_CHOICES = (
            (MS_DRAFT, "Draft"),
            (MS_NEW, "New"),
            (MS_SENT, "Sent"),
            (MS_DELETED, "Deleted"),
            (MS_ERROR, "Error"),
            (MS_GEOMSG, "Geo-msg"),
        )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sender = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)
    subject = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)
    headers = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default='', max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
    planned = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
    expires = models.DateTimeField(default=plus_one_month)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=MS_CHOICES, default=MS_DRAFT)
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def mark_deleted(self):
        self.status = MS_DELETED
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.updated = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        super(Message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'messages'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode('{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}'.format(self.sender, self.subject, self.locale, self.planned, self.expires))
```

However, when I crate tables, table `messages` looks like this:

```
mysql> desc messages;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sender  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| headers | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| planned | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expires | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locale  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice, that `status` field doesn't have a default value.
The same case applies for a few other tables and fields.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a side note ```updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))``` will evaluate at runtime, so the default will just be whenever you start the server.  Use ```default=datetime.utcnow``` to make it a callable that executes when you're actually saving the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. Django defaults are applied in code, not in the database.

Comment: Indeed. It seems I'm somehow blind and something else didn't work, rather than that particular code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an approach but it seems odd that it cannot be activated by config

it does more than what you asked but you can remove the part you don't want

This code use the pre_save signal for ALL model (sender=MyModel could restrict it to a single model)

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def validator(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for f in  instance._meta.get_fields():
        # apply default if existing
        if hasattr(f,'default') and not f.default == models.fields.NOT_PROVIDED and not getattr(instance, f.name):
            setattr(instance, f.name, f.default() if callable(f.default) else f.default )
        #format decimal properly
        elif isinstance(f, models.DecimalField) and f.decimal_places and getattr(instance, f.name):
            setattr(instance, f.name, f"{{:.{f.decimal_places}f}}".format(float(getattr(instance, f.name))))
    # validate object (but for django simple-history table): create quite some error if blank=True is not set along null=True
    if not issubclass(sender, HistoricalChanges):
        instance.full_clean()
```

Note:I know this is an old post but I found this issue while searching so it felt like a good place to share and get feedback